# How to say "one thing or another" in German

Tags: english-to-german

So, I was trying to find a way of saying something like "I can say one thing or another in German", mainly to try to run away from the classic "Ich kann sprechen ein bisschen deutsch".

But I couldn't find a proper way to say the "one thing or another" part, the only translation I could find was this:

> Ich kann sagen, **eine Sache oder ein anderes**

But it sounds strange somehow...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your "classical" sentence is wrong. It is either *Ich kann ein bisschen Deutsch.* or *Ich kann ein bisschen Deutsch sprechen.* or *Ich spreche ein bisschen Deutsch.*.

Comment: I would translate 'one thing or another' as 'die ein oder andere Sache',  but that doesn't fit to 'I am able to speak'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phrase that would be closest is **das eine oder andere**.

So you'd get:

> Ich kann das eine oder andere sagen. *or*
>   Ich kann das ein oder andere Wort. *or*
>   Ich kann den ein oder anderen Satz. *etc.*

Comment: wieso nicht auch "ich kann eines oder anderes sagen"?

Comment: @mle Weil das keinen Sinn ergibt.

Comment: @Jan, Ich wollte es nicht, ich habe etwas neues gelernt! ;) Danke!

Answer (score 6):

In this context you should say something like

> Ich kann schon das eine oder andere auf Deutsch sagen.

or

> Ich kann schon einige Dinge auf Deutsch sagen.

or more neutral

> Ein wenig Deutsch kann ich schon sprechen.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context you could also say: 
Dies oder das ...
Dieses oder jenes ...
Das eine oder andere ...

In your example sentence it would be said/written as follows:

> Ich kann (schon) dies oder das auf Deutsch sagen.
>
> Ich kann (schon) dieses oder jenes auf Deutsch sagen.
>
> Ich kann (schon) das eine oder andere auf Deutsch sagen.

*schon* is optional and means already, and would show that you are a beginner!